# Loop through array of values with Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have:

```
var someValues = [1, 'abc', 3, 'sss'];
```

How can I use an arrow function to loop through each and perform an operation on each value?

Comment: damn missed that page.  Yea I did look this up thanks

Comment: There is no reason to use an arrow function. If you want to loop through an array, use a `for of` loop!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In short:

```
someValues.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

If you care about index, then second parameter can be passed to receive the index of current element:

```
someValues.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log(`Current index: ${index}`);
    console.log(element);
});
```

> Refer here to know more about Array of ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: There is one minor drawback about `forEach`: you can’t break out of this loop using a `break` statement or return from the enclosing function using a `return` statement. More on this [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/es6-in-depth-iterators-and-the-for-of-loop/)

Answer (score 24):

One statement can be written as such:

```
someValues.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

or multiple statements can be enclosed in `{}` like this:

```
someValues.forEach(x => { let a = 2 + x; console.log(a); });
```

Comment: thanks.  Is there a way to specify the array inside the expression somehow too so I wouldn't need to create an array first and one less line of code?

Comment: yes, if the array is in a variable: `arr.forEach(x => console.log(arr))` prints the entire array as many times as there are elements. Does not work for `[1, 2].forEach...` You can not use `this`; it refers to the "this" of the calling environment

Comment: Why is it not possible to have two parameters in an arrow loop function, like someValues.forEach(x,y => console.log(x,y)); **UUps**, I see the answer above that treats exactly that.