# Input cicle with WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using WebDriver with JavaScript.

I am trying to enter multiple variables with forEach but it does not work

for example:

```
["1", "2", "3"].forEach((query) => {
                await driver.findElement(By.css(Input)).sendKeys(query);
                await driver.findElement(By.css(save)).click();
            });
```

WebDriver just enter 123 and then press save. Or press save then enter 123

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array of values with Arrow Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763768/loop-through-array-of-values-with-arrow-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success with a structure like this -- pass each query test as an individual element within an array, contained inside the parent array.

```
forEach([
 ['1'],
 ['2'],
 ['3']
]).it('Does a Thing', ( query )=>{
 await driver.findElement(By.css(Input)).sendKeys(query);
 await driver.findElement(By.css(save)).click();
});
```

Comment: Still not solved.
I tried to use while but now WD enter only first char

Comment: What does your latest version look like?

Comment: Done. while was a bad solution. Im just use for.
Thanks for trying to help.