# JavaScript: Can variables be used as for loop statements?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console, iteration

Why won't something like this would work or even throw an error?

```
const arr = [...Array(5).keys()];
const first = i = 0, second = i < 5, third = i++
for (first; second; third) {
   console.log(arr[i])
}
```

expected result:

[image]

Comment: Because variables store values, not expressions.

Comment: No, because `first`, `second` and `third` don't contain the original expressions; they contain the evaluated *result* of those expressions at the moment you assign them.

Comment: `second = i < 5` evaluates to a _value_, true or false based on whatever i is at the moment it's assigned, it does **not** create something that tracks the changing value of i.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763847

Answer (score 1):

When you use a variable, it gets replaced with the value that was assigned to it, the expression that was used to initialize it is not substituted.

So you're setting `i` to the value of the condition at the time you declare the variable, it doesn't re-execute the condition each time you use the variable.

And you're setting `third` to the initial value of `i++`, it doesn't increment `i` when you use it.

If you want something that tracks and updates the value of `i`, you can use a function.

```js
const arr = [...Array(5).keys()];
let i;
const first = () => i = 0;
const second = () => i < 5;
const third = () => i++;
for (first(); second(); third()) {
   console.log(arr[i])
}
```